# About unique_ptr with custom class: crash when turning out scope?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Codes as following:

```
//test.cpp

#include "fmt/core.h"
#include <memory>
#include <string>


struct node{
    std::string str;
    explicit node(const std::string& str):
            str(str)
    {
        fmt::print("  construct node: {}\n", this->str);
    }
    ~node(){
        fmt::print("  deconstruct node: {}\n", str);
    }
};

bool test(){
    {
        auto str{std::make_unique<std::string>("str")};
    } // no problem here
    {
        auto root = std::make_unique<node>("root");
        fmt::print("str: {}\n", root->str);
    } // crash here
    return true;
}
```

```
//main.cpp
bool tree_test();
bool test();

int main() {
    //bree_test();
    //tree_test();
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Exception 0xc0000005 was thrown just when turn out of the scope. And the crash position is marked in code.
Why does this happen? Is the way using `unique_ptr` wrong?

---

The toolchain is VS Community 2022 (17.3.6).

I guess that the error is caused by class/struct name duplication:
There is a another definition of `node` in another `.cpp` file ( `another.cpp` ). Though it is used only in that file itself, and I have delete all reference to functions in `another.cpp` before posting this issue.
`node` in `another.cpp` has default constructor and deconstructor. I think there might be wrong linking?
If I rename struct `node` in `test.cpp` (or that in `another.cpp`), things go well.
And also, if I put content in `test.cpp` in `main.cpp` like https://godbolt.org/z/7TcYzKrTe, I cannot reproduce this error, too.

---

Thank everyone here. It seems this problem does related to One Definition Rule rule.
The situation is, I am testing a generic printing function for different trees. So, there might be different kinds of class `node`. I did not give them different names, or namespaces.
in `test.cpp` the definition of `node` is:

```
struct node{
    std::string str;
    explicit node(const std::string& str):
            str(str)
    {
        fmt::print("  construct node: {}\n", this->str);
    }
    ~node(){
        fmt::print("  deconstruct node: {}\n", str);
    }
};
```

while in `another.cpp`, the definition of `node` is:

```
struct node{
    double p;
    std::string str;
    bnode* left;
    bnode* right;
};
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using, with which flags?

Comment: @JakobStark, with MSVC i get `Exception 0xc0000005 encountered at address 0xb9b470: Access violation reading location 0xcccccc04`. With MinGW i get `signal = SIGTRAP`.

Comment: What is the "fmt"?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Which MSVC and fmt versions are you using?

Comment: @molbdnilo, it is fmtlib. If I delete `include "fmt/core.h"` and `fmt::print()`, crash occurs too.

Comment: cannot reproduce without fmt https://godbolt.org/z/9W7WxYKsb

Comment: In that case, you should not have included it in the question. Please read about the [mcve].

Comment: with fmt I cant get it to link :/ Though I suppose thats either my ignorance or godbolt issue https://godbolt.org/z/evM4G1e1E

Comment: fwiw, your usage of the unique pointer looks fine

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number you can use fmt as header only lib by defining `FMT_HEADER_ONLY` before including it. But that does not reproduce the issue for me either.

Comment: FYI here is the FMT_HEADER_ONLY godbolt version https://godbolt.org/z/7TcYzKrTe, no error

Comment: more information is required. What compiler version? What flags did you use to compile?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number. Thank you. I have update some info. I don't know if my guessing is correct.

Comment: "There is another definition of `node` in another .cpp file." This is a violation of the One Definition Rule, and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @RaymondChen. Thanks. What should I do to prevent this kind of issue? Just introducing different names or namespaces? Is there any way to hide the symbol of a class (its member functions) if I want use it only in the current `.cpp` file?

Comment: why are there two definitions of `node` ? `node` can be defined in a header and all methods can be defined inline. The header you can include in several source files

Comment: Use an anonymous namespace .and put the type inside that anonymous namespace

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks! The anonymous namespace does help.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  It is my mistake. Though another_node have a same name, its definition is different. I did not add any member functions for it, and it is not in a header file. So, I thought its symbol would not be exposed to other `.cpp` files.